# How to pass and echo data of textareas which are in a loop?

Tags: php, html, for-loop, textarea

I have a scenario in which I don't know the number of textareas which are on my form and I want to save all data of all texareas in different fields of the database.

I print my textareas with a loop in my form like this:

```
<?php
for ($a = 0; $a < count($model_main_heading); $a++) {
    ?>
    <textarea cols="100" rows="5" name="text_area_<?php echo $a+1; ?>">
        Your Text Goes Here....!!!!
        Kindly make new paragraph for your every bullet point :) 
    </textarea>
    <?php
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

Now I want to pass all data of all textareas to another page where I write the query for insertion into database. To get the data of textareas I write the following code but it cannot get all data of all textareas:

```
$model_headings = explode (',', $_POST['model_headings']);
for ($a = 0; $a < count($model_headings); $a++) {
    $b = $a + 1;    
    echo '<br>';
    echo mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text_area_'.$b.''][$a]);
    //echo $text_area[$a];
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: make `name` attribute as array like `name="text_area[<?php echo $a+1; ?>]"`

Comment: Where does `$_POST['model_headings']` come from?

Comment: @colburton i pass it `$_POST['model_headings'] ` from my form

Comment: @AlivetoDie Can you please tell me more i cant understand what i can do as u said above in your comment

Comment: @sunny  check my answer

Comment: Add the part with `model_headings`. You are expecting to have the same amount of textareas as you have `model_headings` (You are counting up to them). This might not be the case.

Comment: @colburton can you explain it in answer with code ??

Comment: As soon as we know all relevant components of your form, you will get an answer.

Comment: Only textarea is relevant :)

Comment: No! You are counting up to the number of elements for `model_headings`. This makes it relevant. And this IS most likely where the error comes from.

Comment: @colburton `model_headings` its working fine, And i have problem in textarea

Comment: Create array-type `name` attribute for your text-area `name` like below(`name="text_area[<?php echo $a+1; ?>]"`):-

    `<?php 
     for($a=0; $a<count($model_main_heading); $a++){?>
      <textarea cols="100" rows="5" name="text_area[<?php echo $a+1; ?>]"> Your Text Goes Here....!!!! Kindly make new paragraph for your every bullet point :) </textarea><br>
    <?php } ?>`

Now on other page when you do like :-

   `echo "<pre/>";print_r($_POST);`

You will see all text-areas values come to you in form of `text_area` array inside `$_POST` array

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
echo mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['text_area_'.$b.''][$a]);
```

paste line

```
echo mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['text_area_'.$b]);
```